# How to get the actual font size used by a chart axis label

Tags: vb.net, charts

I am using a chart (`DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`) and letting the chart decide the font size for the axes labels (`IsLabelAutoFit = True` for each axis).  After the chart is drawn, I want to know the actual font size used.  Microsoft documentation says that `LabelStyle.Font` is for both `Get` and `Set`.  However, the Get always returns the default font size (8 pts) rather than the actual font size used.  How can I get the true font size used by the chart?

```
Dim OriginalXLabelFont As Font = thisChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Font
Dim OriginalXTitleFont As Font = thisChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.TitleFont
```

I expect the `OriginalXLabelFont` to be the actual font size used by the chart, but it always just the default size.  On the other hand, `OriginalXTitleFont` properly gives me the actual Title font size that was used.  However, the title font is fixed, and does not change dynamically when the chart is drawn.  How can I get the axis label font size of the as-drawn chart?

Answer (score 4):

I poked around and found out that the actual font size used by the graph was in a non-public field of the axis call autoLabelFont.  To access it I had to use reflection.

```
    Dim OriginalXLabelFont As Font = GetPrivateFieldValue(thisChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX, "autoLabelFont")
```

...

```
Private Function GetPrivateFieldValue(ByVal thisObject As Object, ByVal propName As String) As Object

    If IsNothing(thisObject) Then Return Nothing

    Dim fi As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = thisObject.GetType().GetField(propName, Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or
                   Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)

    If IsNothing(fi) Then Return Nothing

    Return fi.GetValue(thisObject)

End Function
```